# How to map and persist a Tree using JPA 1

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa

I have a DB table with something like:

```
Person 
ID | ParentID | Name
```

Each person has a parent (only 1). Each person may have N children.

My question is how to map this correctly in an Entity, using JPA 1 and Hibernate. My goal is to have only 1 Java object (my grandparent) that has all the children inside it filled correctly. When I persist my grandparent I expect all children to be correctly persisted also.

What I currently achieved is something like this:

```
 @ManyToOne()
 @JoinColumn(name="PARENTID")
 private Person parent;

 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
 private List<Person> children;
```

When I persist my grandparent everybody is correctly added to my DB but the PARENTID column is NULL which is incorrect.

How can I correctly map this so that the PARENTID is set correctly by JPA/Hibernate?

Comment: Which parentId is null? All of them, or only for the "top-level" object?

Comment: Maybe have a look at http://www.tikalk.com/java/load-a-tree-with-jpa-and-hibernate. For unidirectional tree, the put the `@JoinColumn` on the children, and for bidirectional tree they put the `@JoinColumn` on both parent and children.

Comment: all parentIds are set to null

Comment: maybe it's a time to put bounty on this? :)